# Could not initialize class org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.KotlinGradleBuildServices Android Studio on Mac Machine

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle

I am using a Mac machine and getting below error while synching the project

Error: Could not initialize class org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.KotlinGradleBuildServices

I have tried reinstalling the Android Studio and Enabled the Kotlin plugin but did not work. Is there anyone who got this kind of issue before?

The Android Studio version I am using is Android Studio Chipmunk 2021.2.1 Patch 2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to fix it by updating my `org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin` dependency in my project level gradle file to 1.7.10

Comment: Thanks for the answer, After updating it I am able to build the code but while running the app I am getting below error error: Not sure how to handle query method's return type (java.lang.Object). UPDATE query methods must either return void or int (the number of updated rows).

Comment: That seems to be unrelated. You can create a new question with more details and I can have a look.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it by uninstalling the Kotlin 1.7.10 plugin -> Restart IDE -> Clone fresh project run. It was successfully compiled and running.